# Disable Push Notification topics when iOS App is in background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, background-process, firebase-notifications

I have implemented push notification and subscribe app on different news topics. Web Application is also using same topics to subscribe/unsubscribe notifications.

What i want is basically when user on web in settings menu disable any topic it also disable in iOS app, for that purpose i am using silent notification with content_available. When user disable any topic on web a silent notification is sent to all iOS device for same user. But these silent notifications only unsubscribe to topic whenever user opens the app otherwise they wont subscribe/unsubscribe from any topic.

How can i achieve this when ever i receive silent push notification it subscribe/unsubscribe that specific topic sent in content data without opening the app?

Answer (score 2):

I would use external database to store information about users subscribed to different topics.

1 - create a table in a database that holds topcs and topic ids

2 - create a table that holds ids and tokens of all the users

3 - create a table that relates topics and users

4 - create a script that sends FCM notifications based on the table nr 3  - the script will decide whether to send notification or not

5 - create script (for www and for app settings) to put/delete a user to/from table nr 3

Comment: What you said is the right of way doing it. A quick hack alternate hack to disable upon backgrounding is: just have make a network call to your server to deregister the token upon backgrounding and then re-register upon foregrounding.

Comment: You are right adding external database but our backend team is unable to perform this task on their end, so i have handled this situation in android but i need it to handle on iOS anyway. can u suggest something else?